# Changing host bad for SEO ranking?

Tags: seo, google-ranking

I am moving a small business website to a new host without changing the domain. Will this affect their ranking in Google? Is there any particular way I should change the DNS to make sure that its ranking on Google is not disturbed?

Answer (score 1):

I usually don't see any ranking changes when changing host. I had once the situation where rankings were lower for about a month but then came back to normal. There could have been other reasons for this though.

There are two situations I can think of where rankings could be affected:

- moving strongly interlinked websites to a single host
- moving to a low performance host

Bonus: moving to a host away from the country of your target user group

Answer (score 0):

As long as your website doesn't go down in the process of moving it and you keep the same domain everything should be fine. If your website goes down for a long period of time then you might get indexed by the Googlebot and you might have to wait 4 to 6 weeks to get where you were but this very unlikely. I have changed hosts before several times and I have never encounter this problem though.

Also you can read [this](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/moving-to-a-new-web-host/).